# Got focus Event to handle all textbox

Tags: c#, wpf

This is my coding:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(TextBox), UIElement.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDownEvent,
           new MouseButtonEventHandler(SelectivelyHandleMouseButton), true);
        EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(TextBox), UIElement.GotKeyboardFocusEvent,
          new RoutedEventHandler(SelectAllText), true);

        base.OnStartup(e);
    }

private static void SelectivelyHandleMouseButton(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var textbox = (sender as TextBox);
    if (textbox != null && !textbox.IsKeyboardFocusWithin)
    {
        if( e.OriginalSource.GetType().Name == "TextBoxView" )
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            textbox.Focus();
        }
    }
}
```

I got error in:

> onstartup() method- method cannot be override

Comment: what you want to to do exactly ?

Comment: I think what you really want to do is to subscribe to the `Startup event.` You can do this in your XAML file.

Comment: Can you post your xaml file code .

Comment: can u tell how we can do in xaml file

Comment: In my form more than 30 textbox used. if text box is empty i had set REQUIRED in textbox. while i clicking text box it must be empty. I achive these by using gotfocus event. But to simply the coding.  i need to do single gotfocus() event for multiple textbox

Comment: i need to handle multiple textbox in single gotfocus event for different form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `App.xaml` you need to subscribe to event Startup:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication1.App"
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                 StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml" Startup="Application_Startup">

    <Application.Resources>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

In `App.xaml.cs`:

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    // Your code here
}
```